# Vue.js: where does this info come from?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am following the Vue.js documentation and run [this example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html).

So here is the **index.html** file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="app">
            <h1>Bitcoin Price Index</h1>
            <div v-for="currency in info" class="currency" >
                {{ currency.description }}:
                <span class="lighten">
                    <span v-html="currency.symbol"></span>
                    {{ currency.rate_float | currencydecimal }}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>        
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the **index.js**:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = response.data.bpi))
  },
  
  filters: {
  currencydecimal (value) {
    return value.toFixed(2)
  }
},
})
```

Output:

[image]

(you can copy paste the above code into [here](https://scrimba.com/p/pXKqta/cQ3QVcr))

**Question:** in `index.html`, I do not understand where `{{ currency.description }}` is coming from. `currency` is not even declared as in the `data` of the Vue() instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v-for="currency in info"
```

This property `currency` is one of elements from `info` array.

Answer (score 0):

It is defined in your *.html* file as  `v-for="currency in info"`

Answer (score 0):

See that in the *index.html* file that has a `v-for`. In case he assigns to `currency` each element of `info`. An array of objects is assigned to `info` in mounted

See more about JavaScript for/in Statement [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forin.asp)